# What are the maths behind 'Raiden 2' purple laser?

Tags: mathematics, shoot-em-up

The path of the laser is affected by user input and enemies present on the screen.
Here is a video, at 5:00 minutes the laser in question is shown : [Raiden II (PS) - 1 Loop Clear - Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qd1EuxE-LIs&feature=player_detailpage#t=280s)

**UPDATE**

Here is a test using Inkscape, ship is at bottom, the first 4 enemies are targeted by the plasma.
There seems to be a sort of pattern. I moved the ship first, then the handle from it to form a 45° angle, then while trying to fit the curve I found a pattern of parallel  handles and continued so until I reached the last enemy.
[image]

**Update, 5/26/2012** : I started an XNA project using beziers, there is still some work needed, will update the question next week. Stay tuned !

[image]

**Update : 5/30/2012** : It really seems that they are using Bézier curves, I think I will be able to replicate/imitate a plasma of such grade. There are two new topics I discovered since last time : [Arc length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length), [Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon), first one should help in having a linear movement possible over a Bézier curve, second should help in optimizing the number of vertices. Next time I will put a video so you can see the progress 8-)

Comment: Well, it's a spline of some kind. Possibly [Bézier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). I'm not sure if this question is answerable by anyone other than the original developers. If you're trying to re-create this effect you should show us what you have and tell us what about it isn't working.

Comment: No idea, but it's got a fine of amount of radical to it.

Comment: Having played an unhealthy amount of Raiden, I have my doubts the toothpaste is any kind of closed form curve. It always seemed to keep a fair amount of memory. I suspect it's doing some kind of pathing with a mandatory turn radius.

Comment: @Byte56: Shmup devs/fans are dedicated, I would be surprised if this isn't documented / reverse engineered somewhere by now.

Comment: Looks like it places segments one at a time proceeding out from the ship, with a maximum bend, and each segment either turns towards enemies if any are nearby or in the direction of the ship's movement.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Good point, also your pathing idea is good too. However, I still think spline based on that "snapping" it does.

Comment: @Byte56: Do you mean you think they're solving it as a closed-form equation? When done with discrete sprites like that, an object seeking another in linear increments would be visually identical to any number of spline-based methods. (The only thing distinguishing a spline from a series of connected line segments is continuity at the knots, which discrete sprites would entirely mask the presence/absence of.)

Comment: Also, much of the snapping is not (necessarily) an over-fitting artifact, but the result of enemies quickly appearing and then dying. Well, I guess this gives me an excuse to play a bunch of Raiden tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I still have to code something, will post it here then.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig No, not closed form. It could be either linear increments or sprites placed along a open-ended spline. Would be interesting to know. Let us know what you come up with Aybe.

Comment: @Hackworth Can you tell more about using radicals for this purpose ?

Comment: I agree with Byte56 for possible curve algorithm but something more simple than bezier curve would also be ok (no need of control points). I was thinking about cubic interpolation. Have a look here : http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/miscellaneous/interpolation/. Page link also give one interpolation algorithm (hermite) that give possibility to configure tension/bias. It would give more bending to the curve and maybe changing it runtime would give same "shaking effect" as seen on video.

Comment: @Byte56 I'm on it !

Comment: @tigrou Very interesting, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Aybe I meant radical of this sort: http://drmcninja.com/archives/comic/23p40/

Answer (score 6):

I just created something that may help you.
It was in response to help somebody on the GLBasic forums.

Here is the forum link with my suggestion:
[Random Textured Rolling Hills](http://www.glbasic.com/forum/index.php?topic=8118)

This is written in GLBasic, but I tried to keep it easy to read, so it should be easily converted to any language.

To use it for your needs, you would need to generate your spline data / points.
Replace the 'hill' points in my example with your spline points.
You would only need to add an animation / flickering effect somehow.  Maybe a random texture shift.

The real 'magic' happens in my 'AddPoint' function:

```
FUNCTION AddPoint: h AS THillPoint
    DIMPUSH self.points[], h

    // Is this the very first data point?
    IF LEN(self.points[]) = 1
        self.points[0].pu.Set(0, self.points[0].pm.y - self.texture_ht_up)
        self.points[0].pd.Set(0, self.points[0].pm.y + self.texture_ht_dn)
        RETURN
    ENDIF

    ALIAS h0 AS self.points[-2]  // Reference to the 2nd last point
    ALIAS h1 AS self.points[-1]  // Reference to the last point
    LOCAL angle#
    LOCAL v1 AS TVector
    LOCAL v0 AS TVector

    // Calculate 'p2' of HillPoint - form rectangle with previous point
    angle = ATAN(h1.pm.y - h0.pm.y, h1.pm.x - h0.pm.x)  -90// Angle of the two points

    v1.x = COS(angle) * self.texture_ht_up + h1.pm.x
    v1.y = SIN(angle) * self.texture_ht_up + h1.pm.y
    v0.x = COS(angle) * self.texture_ht_up + h0.pm.x
    v0.y = SIN(angle) * self.texture_ht_up + h0.pm.y
    h0.pu = h0.pu.AverageWith(v0)
    h1.pu.Copy(v1)

    v1.x = COS(angle) * -self.texture_ht_dn + h1.pm.x
    v1.y = SIN(angle) * -self.texture_ht_dn + h1.pm.y
    v0.x = COS(angle) * -self.texture_ht_dn + h0.pm.x
    v0.y = SIN(angle) * -self.texture_ht_dn + h0.pm.y
    h0.pd = h0.pd.AverageWith(v0)
    h1.pd.Copy(v1)
ENDFUNCTION
```

This is where I calculate the final quads / polygons that plots the sprite along the line.

Here's the final results:
[image]

And with the polygons' wireframe turned on:
[image]

Comment: Great I will look at it. BTW, the link you gave is broken.

Comment: The link doesn't appear to be broken for me...

Comment: I just checked Random Textured Rolling Hills link right now, it brings me a 404 error.

Comment: Weird.  It still works for me.  But here's the underlying link: http://www.glbasic.com/forum/index.php?topic=8118

Comment: Broken for me, I tried the home page, it shows 'It works !' and that's it ... weird.

Comment: I suspect you are using IPV6 - in which case you would need to use a proxy (IPV4) - or re-activate it Windows. Other causes could be your ISP blocking it for some reason. European ISP's are really dragging their feet over the change over :( The rolling hills example program is pretty impressive, by the way

Comment: You are right, I can read it from Google Translate but no pictures, downloads, etc. BTW I have both v4 and v6 enabled.

Comment: @Slydog I tested through a proxy (works), I've seen your post about this issue at GLBasic forum. I guess the download link is on the first post, therefore I created an account but I am still waiting for the confirmation email (likely i'm not gonna get it otherwise it'd be here already). Also I tested independently v4 and v6, the same (broken) except that for v6 I cannot access the web anymore.

Comment: @Slydog Hey it's working now, w/o proxy or whatever ! Did you change something on glbasic.com ?

Comment: Nope, nothing changed at GLBasic.com as far as I know.  Glad it's working for you now though.